# org.postgresql.util.PGobject cannot be cast to org.postgresql.util.PGobject

Tags: classcastexception

I'm getting the above-mentioned error from the following (The `println()` call shows that the `resultObj` is indeed a `PGobject`):

```
public List<Search> findSearchesBySearchString(String searchString) throws ClassNotFoundException{
    List<Search> searchResults = new ArrayList<>();
    String queryString = "SELECT s FROM Search s WHERE '"+ searchString +"' = ANY(s.searchstrings)";
    Query query = em.createNativeQuery(queryString);
    List<Object> objectResultsList = query.getResultList();
    for(Object resultObj: objectResultsList){
        System.out.println("***********************************************************"+ resultObj.getClass());
        PGobject resultObject = (PGobject)resultObj; // ClassCastException thrown here
        Search search = new Search();
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can only really happen when you have multiple versions of the Postgresql JDBC driver on your classpath. Maybe one in your webapp and another one in the servlet container itself. Make sure to only have one such jar file.

Comment: The deployments directory(on Wildfly) has a copy of the Postgres JDBC driver. I also also have the same version of the library listed in my Maven dependencies. For that reason, I don't think it's because of a mismatch as you suggest. Have you used this sort of cast in your code before. I found it necessary as a way of taking advantage of PostgresSQL's arrays.I understand they're a relatively new feature - there isn't too much literature around the PGobject.

I also noticed that its documentation says it is used to hold object of unknown type. Would that be the reason my cast is failing?

Comment: I am not suggesting a version mismatch. I am suggesting you have two copies of the JAR file. That would explain the error, even if both JAR have the exact same version. You need to eliminate one of them.